# The logic of macros

Tags: macros, regression, stata

I am new to Stata.
Let's say we have a dataset with `train` and `re78` as variables.

Why does this code work

```
sum train
local a= r(N)*r(mean)                       
        


regress re78 train
outreg2 using TABLE_2.xls, addstat(A, `a') excel
```

but not this

```
sum train
local a= r(N)*r(mean)
sum `a'
```

Both of these codes have the purpose of calling out local variable `a`.

Answer (score 2):

In Stata the term *variable* is reserved for columns in the dataset. Local macros are called that, not local variables.

Why does your second code  fail?  After `sum train` the local macro `a` is calculated as `r(N) * r(mean)` and so should contain the sum or total of values from the last calculation, the application of `summarize`. (You could also just use `r(sum)`.)

Let's suppose that after that your sum contains 42.

Then

```
sum `a'
```

is interpreted as

```
sum 42
```

and the problem then is nothing to do with using a local macro. The problem is that `summarize` has nothing legal to do there. The minimum legal syntax for `summarize` is to specify variable names or no variable names at all, which is interpreted as meaning all variables. But 42, or whatever your sum is, fits neither syntax and it's illegal.

I am not clear what you want this syntax to do, but it is not legal.